# Не получается составить регулярное выражение js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться с регулярным выражением.Хочу получить массив цветов rgb.По началу хотел написать вот так: `rgb\(([\d]{1,3},[\s]?){3}\)`,но проверяя на [сервисе](https://regexr.com/) совпадений нет.Начал писать полное выражение rgb(([\d]{1,3},[\s]?[\d]{1,3})*) и 4 совпадения(кроме последнего), но как так, последовательность же неверная (3числа,  3числа)повторять n кол-во.

```
const сolors = `
  rgb(101, 137, 164),
  rgb(241, 43, 107),
  rgb(146, 100, 161),
  rgb(56, 159, 117),
  rgb(215, 210, 55),
  rgb(0, 0, 0)
  `.match(/rgb\(([\d]{1,3},[\s]?[\d]{1,3})*\)/g);
```

Comment: `/rgba?\(.+?\)/gm`

Comment: а "полное выражение" вас не сработало, потому что вы ищете "число запятая возможно пробел число" повторить несколько раз", в итоге оно не сработает при любом значении, где 2 числа с одним символом

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо за быстрый ответ, ошибку в первом выражении нашел,надо было написать так /rgb\(([\d]{1,3}[\,]?[\s]?)*\)/g.Можете продублировать в ответе,чтобы я мог закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Если поменять разделители из `,` на `;` например, то можно и без регулярки.

Comment: В таком виде получаю..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const сolors = `
  rgb(101, 137, 164),
  rgb(241, 43, 107),
  rgb(146, 100, 161),
  rgb(56, 159, 117),
  rgb(215, 210, 55),
  rgb(0, 0, 0)
`.match(/rgba?\(.+?\)/gm);
  
console.log(сolors);
```